# Busy /dev/gpio. I can shared it?

Tags: devices, c, application

I need shared one device between two C applications. This device is a buzzer. I've try open this with O_NONBLOCK flag, but result is same: device or resource busy.

Is there any possibility to use the device for two applications?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your exact device, I think there is a good reason for the kernel to prohibit concurrent access to it.  To allow both of your programs quasi-concurrent access anyhow, you could introduce a third program that sits between your programs and the device.  This program could open `/dev/gpio` and could accept commands from your actual programs through a UNIX domain socket (`socket(2)`) or named pipe (`mkfifo(3)`).